# React Router: Go back to specific page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a settings page, with a few sub routes:

```
--/home
--/articles
--/settings
  --/Account(default)
  --/Help
  --/About
```

I would like it in such a way: when I'm in any one of the sub pages under settings, and the browser go back in history, it should always go to the (default)Account page. Going back again will follow the normal browser history behavior.

What's the best way of handling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some research, it seems there's no easy way of doing it, discussions in react-router github wouldn't disagree. A [workaround](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/967) seems to be the consensus. Which is a bit raw to my liking, but anything that works is good.

So instead of keeping every sub page under settings with their own route(to be handled by react-router), I have them controlled by state in settings component. And the following event handling is used:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  window.onpopstate= () => {
    if(this.state.currentSubPage !== 'account-settings') {
      this.props.history.push('/settings');
    } else {
      window.onpopstate = null;
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [history](https://reacttraining.com/web/api/Router/history-object):

```
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory"

const history = createHistory()
history.push("/account")
<Router history={history}/>
```